# C# FileInfo, how to change directory?

Tags: c#

I got instance of "`FileInfo`" in C#.

The path of this object such as "C:\path1"
How can I change every related fields(there  are a lot I noticed) to this to "C:\path2"

thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to construct another instance using your new path.

Comment: Do you want to move that file from folder `path1` to folder `path2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) is just a pointer to some existing file and thus the properties are readonly. There are other [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) manipulation classes that allow you to [extract filenames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) only and [combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) them with other paths.

Comment: `FileInfo` just *describes* a file or directory. There's no requirement that it describe a file or that what it describes actually exists&mdash;or even **be** a file. For instance, execution of `FileInfo instance = new FileInfo(  "C:\\" ) ;` is perfectly legal and will give you an instance of `FileInfo` with its `Attribute` flag set to `Hidden|System|Directory` and its `Exists` flag set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the file from "C:\path1" to "C:\path2" here is how you do just that
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will change all of the properties in a FileInfo instance to include your new path. This also moves the file, though -- I'm not sure if that's your intention.

```
myFileInfo.MoveTo(@"C:\path2\" + myFileInfo.Name);
```

If you want to move all of the files from one folder to another you can do this:

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\path1");

var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

foreach (var fileInfo in files)
{
    fileInfo.MoveTo(@"C:\path2\" + fileInfo.Name);
}
```